# Open option dissappeared when right clicking on .wmv files

Tags: windows-10, file-association

When I was browsing through my Videos folder and started right clicking on stuff (sounds noob-ish but in my perspective it isn't), I noticed that .wmv files weren't associated with Windows Media Player.

So I tried to re-associate them to WMP, it seems to work at first, but when I right click on any .wmv file it still says `Open with MediaShow` or something like that (Not even a Play option appears). I searched on google for a solution and most of them pointed to a registry change, so I tried that, but that didn't work.

At that point I decided to uninstall MediaShow to see if the hijack would be reversed, restarted, and the problem seemed to be gone, but I seem to have made the problem worse: The `Open with MediaShow` option was gone and it didn't even revert back to a Open button. And on top of that, when I double click the file now the `How would you like to open this file?` dialog appears.

I am somewhat lost on how to fix this nonsense as I don't know the specifics on how MediaShow hijacked the extension. I am running on Windows 10 Home x64.

Comment: Right-click a .WMV file and click Properties. Click Change > select WMP. Does it work?

Comment: nope. doesn't change anything.

Comment: See if resetting WMP as default using Default Apps helps. If that doesn't do it, then upload a file type dump online for `.WMV` files? You can generate one using [FileTypeDiag](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/filetypediag-dump-file-association-info/)

Comment: The specific WMP I'm using doesn't appear there.

Comment: anyways, here's what you asked for: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0phh_L538HANHpYX1VZWnVGTGM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click `Start`, click `Programs and Features`
2. Click `Turn Windows features on or off`
3. Expand `Media Features`
4. Uncheck `Windows Media Player` and click OK.

Repeat steps 1-3, and this time enable the check box for `Windows Media Player`, and click OK.

Comment: This may sound like complete non-sense to you, but I'm using a older version of WMP because the current version doesn't support DVD playback. And I've already disabled the newer one through normal means, but I will give your idea a shot anyway.

Comment: Even with the newer WMP enabled, the problem still isn't solved.

Comment: (and by that I meant I tried already)

Comment: Can you upload a new .WMV file association dump?